# Asp form helpers not creating route correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-core, html-helper

I'm having some trouble with the form helpers on my .net Core MVC project.  I have the following form:

MyForm.cshtml

```
<div id="myDiv" class="row">    
<br />
<form asp-controller="testing" asp-action="MyForm" asp-route-returnUrl="returnHome">
    <input type="text" asp-for="Name" name="Name" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and my actions in TestingController.cs

```
[HttpGet, Route("testing/MyForm/{code}")]
public IActionResult MyForm(string code)
{
    return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult MyForm(FormVM request)
{
    // do stuff
    // return some view
    return View();
}
```

The idea here is that a user lands on the MyForm page with some sort of code (typically a GUID but other strings are possible).  Then they fill out the form and submit it.  The problem I'm having is that the helpers for the form are not building out the form's action correctly (or at least not the way it says they should here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms).

If I use the code above and inspect the html the form's action will be "testing/MyForm/asdf?returnUrl=returnHome" (the code used was "asdf").

I get that same result whether or not I include the `asp-controller` piece.

If I use `<form asp-route="MyForm">` then the form's action will just be blank, `<form action method="post">`

What I need is for action to be "testing/MyForm?returnUrl=returnHome" but the value from my {code} keeps creeping in.  Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here:  https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/6420

I don't like it but the answer is to deliberately kill the variable in question.  In my case here, using

```
<form asp-controller="testing" asp-action="MyForm" asp-route-code="" 
                                          asp-route-returnUrl="returnHome">
```

does the trick.